# In bash, can you use a function call as a condition in an if statement?

Tags: bash

here's what i'm trying to achive:

```
function f1() {
  return 0
}

function f2() {
  return 0
}

if [[ f1 && f2 ]]; then
  echo "success"
else
  echo "fail"
fi
```

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You don't use `[[` (or `[`) when running a command and checking the result code.

```
if f1 && f2 ; then
  echo "success"
else
  echo "fail"
fi
```

Comment: Remember `return 0` means `true` because this is based on exit-codes and not boolean logic.

Answer (score 7):

Yes. You can do this by checking against a return by means of echo (although not a strict return):

`if [[ "$(f1)" == "whatever" ]]` works

See this page for more on function return values. It also has a couple of good comments specifically talking about if statements.

http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/return-values-bash-functions

Comment: You can't use `$(...)` to get return values.